# How can I retry a Dio request if the request doesn't complete because the device is disconnected from the Internet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, get, dio

I have a request that is a GET method to get data from an API using Dio. If the internet is disconnected while the request is in progress, no data will be available. So how can the request retry after the internet connection is back? I'd like this retry to be done automatically in the background instead of popping up a dialog for the user to interact with. Please tell me the solution.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

solution 1

When the internet is gone , activate a timer ,it will periodically call the method.
then the network is came inactive the timer

solution 2

When the internet is gone , use **workmanager** ,**AlarmManager** , **cron** like plugin , it will also run task periodically ,so use those kind of plugin to call you'r methods

Comment: I'd like this retry to be done automatically in the background instead of popping up a dialog for the user to interact with. Can you give me any other ideas?

Comment: please edit you'r question accordingly

Comment: i'm also edited my Answer